# Android draw performance with Xamarin Forms using dynamic resource or specifying exact numbers?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I notice that Android is a lot slower than iOS when it comes to drawing out forms.

Can anyone tell me is there any difference in the speed taken to draw these three:

```
<Grid ColumnSpacing="{DynamicResource TemplateColumnSpacing}"
  HeightRequest="{DynamicResource DefaultGridHeight}"
  Padding="{DynamicResource GridGridPadding}">
</Grid>

<Grid ColumnSpacing="10"
  HeightRequest="50"
  Padding="5">
</Grid>
```

Comment: What is the three of "draw these three"? What is the project you use these?